# SharePoint 2013 PDF digital signature withing SharePoint

Tags: pdf, sharepoint-2013, digital-signature

I was trying to see if a PDF file can be signed digitally within SharePoint 2013 without downloading and uploading the document ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: is it possible to sign a pdf document within the sharePoint without downloading and uploading the document ?

Comment: write a farm solution and use some external dlls to achieve this. Shouldn't be a big issue